# Array List Size Equal Zero When Remove Object From It

Tags: android, arraylist

I have array list, I used it in adapter class. All things worked good but when I delete specific index from the array list(in my case `data`) the size of array list equal zero.

Here is my Adapter class

```
public class MainLocalListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public static final int LIMIT_LIST_COUNT = 20;
private Activity activity;
private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private int count = LIMIT_LIST_COUNT;
private int customPosition = 0;

public MainLocalListAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    if(count > data.size()) count = data.size();

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;//data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_local_item, null);
        holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.waveTitle2); // title
        holder.textView.setTypeface(UtiliShare.getTf());

        holder.btnCancel = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btndel);
        holder.btnCancel.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);  

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
         holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    if(!data.isEmpty()) {
        HashMap<String, String> song = data.get(position);
        holder.btnCancel.setTag(position);
        holder.textView.setText(song.get(UtiliShare.KEY_TITLE));
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView btnCancel;
}

private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainLocalListAdapter.this.activity, ""+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        data.remove((Integer) v.getTag());

        // Here data.size = 0 ????????????
        int nval = data.size();
        Log.d("list", ""+nval);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

public int getCustomPosition() {
    return customPosition;
}

public void setCustomPosition(int cPosition) {
    customPosition = cPosition;

    int nval = (data.size() - customPosition); 
    if(nval < LIMIT_LIST_COUNT) this.count = nval;
    else  count = LIMIT_LIST_COUNT;
}


}
```

I don't have error because I check data size before get data from it in `getView()`.

How can I fix this??

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but you are trying to remove an object with an Integer key from a hashmap containing String keys...

Comment: I am try to remove hashmap from arraylist was stored in array list by index. example: arraylist size = 5 ,I want remove third one(3) from array list.

Comment: what is the value of `v.getTag()` is showing in `Toast`

Comment: v.getTag() = row position in listview.

Comment: you should use `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` for detect which row is clicked. and then u should delete the data from `data` arrayList. i have done this in my project. if u want, i can share my procedure .

Comment: Thanks for yore help. But I used `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` in another work, it is also clickable. this `getTag` give me correct position but my problem is when I use `data.remove((Integer) v.getTag());` the data size equal 0.

Comment: ok, would try this: `int i = (Integer) v.getTag(); data.remove(i);`. by the, is `(Integer) v.getTag()` giving the right position of the row ?

Comment: in your `onCreate` method u can apply `setOnItemClickListener()` on your listview. which will only work for the listview. your `mOnClickListener` will not be effected for this.

Comment: have check the size of `data` before deleting any entry from it?

Comment: Thank you @Shoshifor your interest. I found problem, I am point secondary array list to  main array list but when clear secondary array list that's also clear main list which pass to adapter.( I mean main array list, secondary array list and `data` array list have same data, When edit one of them that's effect on all). Thank you again. [pointers](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/)

Comment: it's ok. glad to know that u have found the problem :)